# Store in table when separate column as comma and row as tilt in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to store data in a table using SQL Server 2008 when front-end send the data in form of columns separated by comma and row separated by tilt sign.

I got the comma separated values only from stackoverflow.

Now I need this for multiple columns.

for example

From front-end:

```
ProductId, Color~
1, red~
1, blue~
1, green~
2, null~
3, purple~
3, green
```

In back-end:these data should store in a table format

Comment: Very unclear - can you elaborate and **show us** a sample of the data being sent by your front-end, and how you would like to store that in SQL Server?

Comment: Give us Input & Output sample.

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
USE [YourDB]
GO


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

/*Change name if needed*/
CREATE PROCEDURE uspInsertFromString 
@Str NVARCHAR(MAX)

WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    DECLARE @wrk_hr NVARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @wrk_code NVARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @active BIT

    DECLARE @IND INT
    DECLARE @StrRes NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @StrRes2 NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @IND = CHARINDEX('~',@Str)

    WHILE(@IND > 0)
    BEGIN

        SET @StrRes = SUBSTRING(@Str, 1,  @IND-1)
        SET @StrRes2 = SUBSTRING(@StrRes, CHARINDEX(',', @Str)+1, LEN(@Str))

        SET @wrk_hr = CAST(SUBSTRING(@StrRes, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @Str)-1) AS VARCHAR(20))
        SET @wrk_code = CAST(SUBSTRING(@StrRes2, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @StrRes2)-1) AS VARCHAR(20))
        SET @active = CAST(SUBSTRING(@StrRes2, CHARINDEX(',', @StrRes2)+2, LEN(@Str)) AS BIT)

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_timesheet_entry] (wrk_hr, wrk_code, active ) VALUES (@wrk_hr, @wrk_code, @active) 

        SET @Str = SUBSTRING(@Str, @IND+1,  LEN(@Str))

        SET @IND = CHARINDEX('~',@Str)

    END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- Rollback any active or uncommittable transactions before
    -- inserting information in the ErrorLog
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END

END CATCH;
END;

GO
```

Usage:

```
EXEC uspInsertFromString '1, red, 1~1, blue, 0~1, green, 1~2, null, 0~3, purple, 1~3, green, 0~'
```

Comment: thank you sir...It is working excellently....but i want stored procedure for this by inserting the integer,datetime,varchar values.pls modify this and back to me sir

Comment: Need a little more details then. What is your table you want insert into? Columns, fieldtypes etc.

Comment: my table is:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_timesheet_entry](
 [Id] [int] NULL,
 [date_enter] [date] NULL,
 [proj_type] [char](50) NULL,
 [build_no] [char](10) NULL,
 [ticket_no] [int] NULL,
 [wrk_hr] [varchar](20) NULL,
 [wrk_code] [varchar](20) NULL,
 [comments] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [active] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
...................
i want to isert into: wrk_hr,wrk_code,active columns

Comment: thank you so much andlev...it is working.if i find any error i return back to you..

Comment: Happy to be of any help, saravana kumar

Comment: plz help ANDLEV:I have a table as given below:

CREATE TABLE tbl_timesheet_entry

(

    Id int NULL,
date_enter date NULL,
proj_type char(50) NULL,
build_no char(10) NULL,
ticket_no int NULL,
wrk_hr varchar(20) NULL,
wrk_code varchar(20) NULL,
comments varchar(50) NULL,
active bit NULL
)

Here when I enter the date in date_enter column,need to display the entire week details from monday to sunday.now I need the stored procedure for this

Answer (score 0):

To separate this string to elements you can use [nodes() Method of XML data type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx).

First you should convert this string to XML format using [REPLACE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) to get something like:

```
<X><Xi>1</Xi><Xi>red</Xi></X><X><Xi>1</Xi><Xi>blue</Xi></X>
```

and then use `.nodes()` to convert this XML string to the rowset.

```
DECLARE @X XML

SET @X = CAST('<X><Xi>'+REPLACE(
        REPLACE('ProductId, Color~1, red~1, blue~1, green~2, null~3, purple~3, green'
                ,'~','</Xi></X><X><Xi>')
                ,',','</Xi><Xi>')  
                +'</Xi></X>' as XML)

;WITH separatedTable AS 
(
  SELECT a.c.value('(Xi)[1]', 'VARCHAR(1000)') as field1,
         a.c.value('(Xi)[2]', 'VARCHAR(1000)') as field2
    FROM @X.nodes('X') As a(c)
) 
SELECT * FROM SeparatedTable
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/34557)</kbd>